# не хватает реализации atomic cas в std

Tags: c++, атомарность, std-atomic

есть кусок кода из статьи

```
int c;
if ((c = cmpxchg (val, 0, 1)) != 0) {
    //something
}
// cmpxchg(var, old, new): The content of the variable var will be replaced with 
// new if the current value is old. Regardless, the current value of var before the   
// operation is returned.
```

в std отсутствует такая реализация CAS инструкции...

Попытался проэмулировать таким куском кода:

```
std::uint32_t с = 0;
if ((с = std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&val, &c, 1) ? 0 : 1) != 0) {
    //something
}
```

насколько это корректно?

EDIT: с учетом ответа

```
std::uint32_t с = 0;
if (!std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&val, &c, 1)) {
    //something
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

С виду корректно (хоть и криво), но можно проще:

```
std::uint32_t с = 0;
if (!std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&val, &c, 1)) {
    //something
}
```

> так у вас с не присвоена, в итоге.

`atomic_compare_exchange_strong()` сам меняет значения переменных местами и возвращает старое значение в отличии от `cmpxchg()`, который, судя по использованию, только присваивает переменной новое значение (при условии, что старое не изменилось) и возвращает старое значение. Явно присваивать значение `с` в таком случае не нужно, и, вероятно, не правильно.

> но больше интересовало _weak/_strong... будет ли разница

Скорей всего, `*_strong` в данном контексте предпочтительнее, но что именно использовать зависит от алгоритма: `atomic_compare_exchange_weak()` в отличии от `*_strong` может не произвести обмен даже если значение переменной было равно старому и вернуть `false`.

На x86, если что, разницы нет.

Comment: так у вас с не присвоена, в итоге...
но больше интересовало _weak/_strong... будет ли разница

Comment: @xperious, дописал в ответ...

Comment: хм, да, спасибо, не заметил, что функция сама переменную поменяет...
но, кажись, надо так, как я в ответе исправил...

Comment: @xperious, да... здесь моя неточность...